# Setting up Resilio Sync with external storage

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I have a brand new Raspberry Pi 3 which I intend to use as a Resilio Sync server for my office.

I want to use an external 500GB hard drive.

I have spent the last 1.5 hours reading through various tutorials and I can't work out if it's necessary to move the entire OS to the hard drive and boot from it, or whether I can leave the OS on the SD card and just auto-mount the external drive on boot. (From what I gather, there can be problems setting Resilio to use an external drive as its storage path..?)

Can anyone comment on the best way to go about this. Thanks.